# Two timed events one windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm trying to accomplish writing one windows services that will run run two different timed events.  this is what I have, I just want to make sure that it does what i'm intending it to.

What i'm intending is to have one process run every 30 minutes and one process run once every hour.

```
    public static System.Timers.Timer timer1;
    public static System.Timers.Timer timer2;

    public Crawler_Coupon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ControlStation();
    }

    private static void ControlStation()
    {

        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 1800000;
        //timer1.Interval = 10000;
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        timer1.Start();

        timer2 = new Timer();
        timer2.Interval = 3600000;
        //timer1.Interval = 10000;
        timer2.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent2);
        timer2.Start();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for telling us what you are trying to do. Good luck.

Comment: Your code should work perfectly, what is the issues you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

[UPDATED]

Why not just use the **Windows Task Scheduler** to schedule the running of your process?

Comment: I want to keep it as a service for background processing and security.

Comment: Sorry, I meant use the "Windows Task Scheduler". Use the "Run whether user is logged on or not" option, and Task Scheduler will run your task in the background (non-interactive desktop).

Answer (score 1):

[**Update**]

Is there a specific reason that this needs to be a windows service? It isn't a best practice to create a windows service to perform intermittent tasks.

You may want to create a console app or 2 and setup 2 scheduled tasks that run on those intervals.

[Windows Service with multiple timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080481/windows-service-with-multiple-timers)

Comment: Preference, if this is such a hard thing to do I might split it into two

Comment: You could use a single timer that is a common factor of the timing intervals. You set up a timer that goes off once every 30 minutes, and you check how long it's been since you did each one and whether to do it or not.